# Windows 11 file explorer no longer shows thumbnails for PNG images

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, png, thumbnails

Thumbnails for `.jpg`, `.webp`, `.mp4`, and other file formats seem to work just fine, it's only `.png` files that don't work.

Things I've tried:

- Removing my thumbnail cache using the disk cleanup utility
- Toggling "Always show icons, never thumbnails" on and then off again in File Explorer Options
- Changing the default `.png` app from Photos to a different app, then back to Photos (that actually made the problem worse, because now windows is assigning the files this ugly blurry default icon instead of the Photos app icon)
- Restarting my computer
- Making sure Windows is up to date
- Making sure my graphics driver is up to date
- (From [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/png-thumbnails-not-showing/51adc66a-37a9-4ba2-833b-594efedbd040))
  Press Windows key + R
  Type: ie4uinit.exe -show
  Hit Enter
- Restarting my graphics driver with `Windows key + Ctrl + Shift + B`
- From `C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`, delete all `thumbcache` and `iconcache` files
- Ran `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`, which showed "No component store corruption detected. The operation completed successfully."
- In Windows Settings > Apps > Apps & Features > Microsoft Photos > Advanced options, I clicked Reset, then rebooted again.

Yet still, not a single `.png` file on my computer shows a proper thumbnail anymore. See screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of broken thumbnails]

How do I get my `.png` thumbnails back?

---

It seems [other users on the Microsoft forums are having this issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/png-thumbnails-not-showing/51adc66a-37a9-4ba2-833b-594efedbd040) as of this week:

> I have the exact same problem.   It started a couple days ago out of the blue.   I tried all the steps listed but this is still happening.  I've seen this sort of thing on other forums and there doesn't seem to be a fix other than to re-load windows which is a pain for a sysadmin with tools to reinstall and re-configure.  Maybe the next update will fix it....but in the meantime, I'll just guess between the txt files and the png files on my desktop....

Comment: Since you are on Windows 11.  You can perform a DISM Reset command on the Photos application itself.  I would try that.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried running a DISM ScanHealth command and it came back clean (question edited with details). I can't find any info on how to run a Reset command on the Photos application.

Comment: ScanHealth scans the integrity of the WinSxS folder.  [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/reset-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2022-ps) is the module I was suggesting you use.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried using the Reset button on the Photos app in the Apps & Features pane, which I read is equivalent to that. Unfortunately still no dice.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the file extension file association? [This](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html) requires a free forum account, but they have a registry file, that should help with that.  I would try that

Comment: @Ramhound That looks to be a `.reg` file designed for Windows 10, from a forum I don't recognize, that has contents that I don't fully understand, including magic numbers and hashes that as far as I know could be specific to Windows 10. Thank you for the suggestion, but I am going to hold off until someone says that they've had this problem and were able to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Temporary fix was to set the .png files to always open with paint.net. Not the most desirable solution but at least I got the thumbnails to show.

Comment: The same problem. Also affects icons on the Taskbar of the Store apps. Installing Paint.NET and setting it as default exclusively for PNGs restored the thumbnails - and the Store icons. How?

Answer (score 2):

The solution presented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1752352/thumbnails-only-png-and-some-icons-on-taskbar-stop-showing-windows-10) by @Coder-M worked for me. It is for people that installed Google Drive.

In sum, go to `HKEY_USERS\[Your-User-ID]\Software\Classes\.png\shellex` and delete `E357FCCD-A995-4576-B01F-234630154E96`.

To find `Your-User-ID` you can go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist` and look for the entry with a value like `\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Users\[Your-User-Name]\NTUSER.DAT`. It is usually the one ending with `0001`.

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread through Google and I just now fixed mine. I changed the default app to open .png from Picasa (yes, I still have this. lol) to Paint.net and BINGO! I opened Windows Explorer and my .PNG thumbnails showed the pic instead of a generic icon. Cheers all!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open File Explorer
2. Select "This PC" on the left
3. Click the "..." on the ribbon
4. Select "Options" from the drop down menu
5. Click on the "View" Tab
6. Under the Advanced Settings Section
7. Under Files and Folders
8. Uncheck the "Always show icons, never thumbnails"
9. Click the "Apply" Buttom
10. Click "OK"

[View a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krhKb.png)

Not sure why this got changed on my pc, but it did, and these steps fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure this will make the .png files work again?

Comment: Are you sure about this solution? It seems counterintuitive that telling the OS to "never show thumbnails" gets thumbnails to show again.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the methods including DISM, sfc /scannow, cleaning up thumbnails etc.

What actually helped me is installing SageThumbs (https://www.cherubicsoft.com/en/projects/sagethumbs/) - that's a small program that does the job for creating thumbnails for images in the system. You could also try other software that's generating thumbnails like MysticThumbs.

I know it's not a *solution solution*, it's just a workaround but couldn't find anything would work besides SageThumbs or trying to reinstall the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

Download and run this reg file. You might need to log off & on or reboot after, but not always.

https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/52473d1449507905-default-file-type-associations-restore-windows-10-a-png.reg

File comes from this forum post:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does this work on Windows 11, and do you know how/why it works?